# Is there anyway to "hard delete" a project in Google Cloud?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Google Cloud projects default to "soft deleting", which count against your project quota for 30 days - https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects

Is there a way to "hard delete" projects so that they don't count against quota? I am aware that you can request quota increases, but I believe that takes 48 hours.

Also, is there no way to list deleted projects?

```
gcloud project list
```

only lists active projects - https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/projects/list

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to instantly delete a project. However if you remove yourself from a project (leaving it to another owner) then it won't count against your quota.

Comment: how to leave a project in console ?

Comment: Go to https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/iam for the project, check all boxes with your account, then click remove access button.